# Get the output with check_output even with a non-zero exit status

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, output, return-code

I use `subprocess.check_output` a number of times in a script of mine, but I just ran into an issue with an external application. `OpenVPN` in this case.

When openvpn is called with the `--help` parameter, which I want to parse in my script, it returns `1` as its exit code. `check_ouput` chokes on the non-zero exit code and fails with the following message:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['openvpn', '--help']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

**Q:** I don't understand why openvpn does this, but how can I have `check_output` give me the output, even with a non-zero return code?

*edit:* I used the exact same code with `--show-digests` or other parameters and all seemed to work just fine.

```
output = check_output(["openvpn", "--show-digests"])
```

Comment: Python 3.5+ has `subprocess.run()` which is a more versatile overall design. It takes some getting used to, but it will produce an object which contains the output, the exit code, and a smattering of additional state information for the process you ran. In brief, you want `result = subprocess.run(['openvpn', '--help'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout` (no `check=True` because you *expect* it to fail).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) the output is available in the `.output` attribute of the `CalledProcessError` exception.

So something like this should work:

```
try:
    result = subprocess.check_output(...).stdout
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    result = exc.output
```

Comment: With this I get the following error, when handling the exception: `NameError: name 'CalledProcessError' is not defined`

Comment: @boolean.is.null:  Updated answer. `CalledProcessError` lives in the `subprocess` module.

Comment: I should have realised that on my own, thank you for the help!